# Async XML File Writing C#

Tags: c#, xml, multithreading

I want to read and write to a XML file which is already existing, I want it to do it in another thread so that the main ui thread will not be blocked while the file it's been read or written.

```
private Event ReadXMLFile()
{
  String workingDir = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory();

   xmlDoc = XDocument.Load("Data.xml");
   var event = (from item in xmlDoc.Descendants("Event")
            where item.Element("id").Value == id
            select new Event
            {
                id = item.Element("id").Value,
                title = item.Element("title").Value,
                Start = DateTime.Parse(item.Element("start").Value),
                End = DateTime.Parse(item.Element("end").Value),
                contacts = item.Element("contacts").Elements("contact").Select(c => new Contact
                {
                    Id = c.Element("id").Value,
                    Name = c.Element("name").Value
                }).ToList()
            }).FirstOrDefault();

  return event;
}

private async void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   this.button1.Enabled = false;
   Event t = await Task.Run(() => this.ReadXMLFile());
   this.button1.Enabled = true;
}
```

I'm currently doing it like this.Is there a better way to achieve this?

Comment: You could use `ReadAsync` instead.  You only need `Task.Run` if you're doing CPU intensive code.

Comment: That code doesn't _do_ anything except read up to the first node in the document and then close it.  What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft I just updated the question with the full code that is been used

Comment: @RasheenRuwisha That's a completely different question now! And it still doesn't do anything with the data. This simply wastes the answerers' time

Comment: In any case, `XDocument` has a `LoadAsync` too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'm currently doing it like this.Is there a better way to achieve this?

No.  You're doing the right thing.  While XDocument.LoadAsync exists and you can load the XML like this:

```
static async Task<XDocument> LoadXmlAsync(string path)
{
    using (var file = System.IO.File.OpenRead(path))
    {
        var doc = await XDocument.LoadAsync(file, LoadOptions.None, System.Threading.CancellationToken.None);
        return doc;
    }
}
```

You have significant work to do beyond the XML parsing.  And so using Task.Run with a synchronous method will offload all that work to a background thread.

Comment: Thanks for this, I'll change the file loading to this method!